# How to cancel and resume texlive installation?

Tags: texlive, installing

My Internet connection is slow and noisy. So, at a time about 3406 package installation is difficult. I started installation using `./install-tl` it is easy. Installation output looks like --

```
Installing to: /usr/local/texlive/2016
Installing [0001/3406, time/total: ??:??/??:??]: 12many [376k]
Installing [0002/3406, time/total: 00:11/19:21:11]: 2up [66k]
Installing [0003/3406, time/total: 00:17/25:28:14]: Asana-Math [482k]
Installing [0004/3406, time/total: 00:27/19:19:14]: ESIEEcv [137k]
Installing [0005/3406, time/total: 00:38/23:41:21]: FAQ-en [4971k]
```

If there was any method that I install 100 package firstly then cancel , next 100 package and next 100 package, it would be very easy for me to install full texlive.

Comment: You could download the `.iso` file of the complete distribution. It's a few GB large, but many download manager are able to resume paused downloads.

Comment: @samcarter but you'd probably have to update it anyway. Another way would be to make a local repository, mirroring an existing one using rsync. It is very good on slow connections and can certainly restarted at will. Then when you have a complete copy, you just Install from your local repository. Yes, it requires a bit of technical knowledge, but there are good guides to rsync online.

Comment: When you have an rsync copy if a texlive version that will get updates in the future (texlive 2016 will not, but let's assume it would) then next time you run rsync on your local repository, it will only download the stuff that have been changed. Thus idea for slow connections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible with current installation system. The best you can do is download/copy/rsync the `tlnet` directory from CTAN. This can be done in steps, in particular if you use `rsync`. Then you can install from that directory.

As mentioned above, downloading the `iso` image is probably not a good idea if you plan to use `tlmgr update`, since so many packages have changed already since released of the image.

Comment: would you give the exact command using `rsync` which is appropriate for me in Bangladesh?

Comment: See http://tug.org/texlive/acquire-mirror.html

Comment: In that link they provide `rsync -a --delete rsync://somectan/somepath/systems/texlive/tlnet/ /your/local/dir`. If I use `rsync -a --delete http://ctan.math.illinois.edu/systems/texlive/tlnet /home/alhelal/Downloads`, is it ok? see my network installtion output https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/HbthR68DZK/

Comment: If the installation starts then yes, it is ok, otherwise there would be problems I guess.

Comment: ssh: Could not resolve hostname http: Name or service not known
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(226) [Receiver=3.1.0]

Comment: You cannot sync over the http protocol...

Comment: Then what can I do?

Comment: I was trying to install from network installation. After install 2488 in 5 hours network connection fail and installation aborted. `Installing [2488/3611, time/total: 05:56:21/08:34:31]: philex [243k]
TLPDB::_install_package: downloading did not succeed
Installation failed.`

Comment: You need to first use rsync to download the tlnet folder to your hard drive and then install from there.

Comment: can I start installation before completing the rsync?

Comment: How to start the installation? Will I use `./install-tl`?