# What is the actual rsync command to install texlive offline?

Tags: installing, texlive-2018

http://tug.org/texlive/acquire-mirror.html In this link they provide `rsync -a --delete rsync://somectan/somepath/systems/texlive/tlnet/ /your/local/dir.`

If I use `rsync -a --delete http://ctan.math.illinois.edu/systems/texlive/tlnet /home/alhelal/Downloads`, is it ok?

See my network installation output -

```
alhelal@VimLaTeX:~/Downloads/install-tl-20180512$ sudo ./install-tl
ABORTED TL INSTALLATION FOUND: installation.profile (in /home/alhelal/Downloads/install-tl-20180512)
Do you want to continue with the exact same settings as before (y/N): n
Loading http://ctan.math.illinois.edu/systems/texlive/tlnet/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb
Installing TeX Live 2018 from: http://ctan.math.illinois.edu/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
Platform: x86_64-linux => 'GNU/Linux on x86_64'
Distribution: net  (downloading)
Using URL: http://ctan.math.illinois.edu/systems/texlive/tlnet
Directory for temporary files: /tmp/n_zqONraIW

======================> TeX Live installation procedure <=====================

======>   Letters/digits in <angle brackets> indicate   <=======
======>   menu items for actions or customizations      <=======

 Detected platform: GNU/Linux on x86_64

 <B> set binary platforms: 1 out of 17

 <S> set installation scheme: scheme-full

 <C> set installation collections:
     40 collections out of 41, disk space required: 5465 MB

 <D> set directories:
   TEXDIR (the main TeX directory):
     /usr/local/texlive/2018
   TEXMFLOCAL (directory for site-wide local files):
     /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local
   TEXMFSYSVAR (directory for variable and automatically generated data):
     /usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-var
   TEXMFSYSCONFIG (directory for local config):
     /usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-config
   TEXMFVAR (personal directory for variable and automatically generated data):
     ~/.texlive2018/texmf-var
   TEXMFCONFIG (personal directory for local config):
     ~/.texlive2018/texmf-config
   TEXMFHOME (directory for user-specific files):
     ~/texmf

 <O> options:
   [ ] use letter size instead of A4 by default
   [X] allow execution of restricted list of programs via \write18
   [X] create all format files
   [X] install macro/font doc tree
   [X] install macro/font source tree
   [ ] create symlinks to standard directories

 <V> set up for portable installation

Actions:
 <I> start installation to hard disk
 <P> save installation profile to 'texlive.profile' and exit
 <H> help
 <Q> quit

Enter command: i
Installing to: /usr/local/texlive/2018
Installing [0001/3611, time/total: ??:??/??:??]: 12many [376k]
Installing [0002/3611, time/total: 00:08/15:41:34]: 2up [66k]
Installing [000
```

I asked a related question in 2017 [How to cancel and resume texlive installation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/368478/how-to-cancel-and-resume-texlive-installation#comment1080840_392069)

Comment: What are you doing? Why don't you just go with the network installation?

Comment: @KeksDose Because my internet connection is very slow. see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/368478/how-to-cancel-and-resume-texlive-installation#comment1081115_392069

Comment: Norbert, who answered your other question, is the author and maintainer of the texlive manager. So just try and follow his advice. If it fails, then ask for help at the texlive mailinglist, see here: https://tug.org/mailman/listinfo/tex-live